# Oracle external tables reject limit option

Tags: oracle, file, external

I have created an oracle external table script to load file data into external table. 
Here's the details of my script.

```
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
   (  
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY DATA_DIR
    ACCESS PARAMETERS 
     ( 
      RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
      LOGFILE log_dir:'file.log'
      BADFILE bad_dir:'file.bad'
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
      OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
      MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL   
     )
    LOCATION (DATA_DIR:'file')
   )
REJECT LIMIT 1
```

When I created the above external table. I have only specified the log file in the log directory. I have never created the bad file in the corresponding bad directory. So while loading the data we never came across any error so far.

But today, we ran into the below error

> Error:
>   in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
>   ORA-29400: data cartridge error
>   error opening file (bad dir)/file.bad

I thought there must have been some junk data in the file only today and hence it was looking to write the bad file. So I created an empty file bad in the corresponding bad dir. 
We got past that error and I was eagerly looking forward to see some junk data in the bad file but it is empty.

Can somebody please explain me why we did not get this error so far if it is mandatory to create an empty bad file.

Comment: Are you sure that `bad_dir` exists and that Oracle has the correct permissions on it?

Comment: Hi Ben, The directory exists with right permissions but the bad files is not present. I created one with permissions only later. Initially I did not create this file and I did not receive any error while querying or loading the external table. This is kind of weird because  if it was a mandatory thing to create a file,  then we should get this error in the first place.